# How to catch DOM element from list by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list of elements from Twig engine, and now I want show input field when user clicks on name of it, but I don't know which attribute I must put on function:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Project Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Delete?</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for projectName in namesOfProjects %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ projectName.project_id }}</td>
            <td>
                <button id="{{ project.ep_id }}">{{ projectName.project_name }}</button>
                <input type="text" class='asd' placeholder="{{ projectName.project_name }}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <button  id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I try to make something like that,but it isn't working (not surprised :))

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#{{ project.ep_id }}').click(function(){
        $(".asd").show();
    });};

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#{{ project.ep_id }}').click(function(){
    $(".asd").hide();
});};
```

I want show/hide input field but especially for single row
[image: I want show/hide input field but especially for single row]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $(this).next(".asd").toggle();
    })
});
```

***Working fiddle:-*** https://jsfiddle.net/rvt4pcaz/

***Note:- Best is*** add a common class to that button and code will become more specific and correct.

```
<button class="show_hide_asd" id="{{ project.ep_id }}">{{ projectName.project_name }}
</button><!-- added class show_hide_asd -->
```

And change code like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show_hide_asd').click(function(){
        $(this).next(".asd").toggle();
    })
});
```

***Reference:-***

[.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

> ***Description:*** Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it
>   retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Comment: It's works great. Do you tell me at couple of words about 'next' func. It's allows us work only with one line of list?
And how could I modify script for showing only one input field at the moment of time? I usually coding on server side, sry :[

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot to add the reference. Let me add that.

Comment: `And how could I modify script for showing only one input field at the moment of time?`-> Please try at your end first and if din't succedd then pls ask a new question. You can address me link and if i will be free i will try to answer or surely some-one will answer you

Answer (score 2):

First need change your markup like following:

```
{% for projectName in namesOfProjects %}
<form action="" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>{{ projectName.project_id }}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="show-hide-field" id="{{ project.ep_id }}">{{ projectName.project_name }}
</button>
            <input type="text" class='asd' placeholder="{{ projectName.project_name }}">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button  id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

Then change your JS code, you actually clicking on same ID because it is not iterating, so I added a class `show-hide-field` on your markup and using to click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.show-hide-field').on("click", function() {
        $(this).next(".asd").toggle();
    })
});
```